# How do I center a string of characters in lines, like how "Align Center" works in text docs in c#?

Tags: c#, string, console

I need to generate something like this:

```
 *
***
 *
```

or

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

Using this approach (because it easier for me to understand) I am able to generate the astericks in that *order* but not in that *alignment* (please not the diamond shape).

I have tried *string.Format()* but no center alignment just *LEFT* and *RIGHT*
var asterickString = new List();

```
if (n % 2 == 0 || n < 1) 
    return null;

for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
       var s = new string('*', i);
       asterickString.Add(s + "\n");
    }
}
   
for (var j = n - 1; j >= 1; --j)
{
    if (j % 2 != 0)
    {
       var k = new string('*', j);
       asterickString.Add(k + "\n");
    }
}

return string.Join("", asterickString);
```

Could someone give me some tips??

Comment: It's not "aligned", per se.. it's a "bunch of spaces then a bunch of *" - you have to vary the number of each to create the illusion of a diamond etc. Nowhere in your code generates any spaces ahead of the asterisks, and the strategies for doing some are many - `new string(' ', n)`, `string.PadLeft(n)`, `string.Format("{0,n}")` etc to name a few. You can read about all these in the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0) - the first is a constructor, the latter two are methods

Comment: First 2 google entries for search "c# asterisk diamond": [this](https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/for-loop/csharp-for-loop-exercise-31.php) and [this](https://forgetcode.com/csharp/2034-printing-a-diamond-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Well, having *screen width* being `screenWidth` you can print *aligned string* like this:

```
private static void PrintLineLeft(string value, int screenWidth) {
  Console.WriteLine(value);
}

private static void PrintLineRight(string value, int screenWidth) {
  if (value.Length >= screenWidth)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
  else
    Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', screenWidth - value.Length)}{value}");
}

private static void PrintLineCenter(string value, int screenWidth) {
  if (value.Length >= screenWidth)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
  else
    Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', (screenWidth - value.Length) / 2)}{value}");
}
```

Then you can put

```
int n = 5;

for (var i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
  PrintLineCenter(new string('*', i), n);

for (var i = n - 2; i >= 1; i -= 2)
  PrintLineCenter(new string('*', i), n);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l78mqY)